# How to run an iOS Application on a real device

Tags: iphone, ios

I had developed an iOS Application using PhoneGap Framework. It's working good and well in simulator. Now I would like to test it in real device i.e iPhone 5 with iOS 6.0. I Googled thoroughly. I have two ways: jailbreak the device (not acceptable to me) or bidding the account in Apple portal.

Is there any other way to test my device my application in real device? Is there anybody here to solve my issue?

Comment: For testing your app in device you need to install provisioning profiles

Answer (score 2):

The official way is to enter the [iOS Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/) (99$), so that you will get the possibility to create certificates and provisioning profiles required. You will also get the chance to distribute your apps through the App Store.

If you are not willing to do it, the other way is jailbreaking your device, which is basically a way to circumvent the need to use certificates for your apps. Your app would then be distributed through an alternative app store like Cydia (i.e, no Apple App Store).

A third option could be getting in touch with an iOS developer friend of yours, and ask him/her to build the app for your device, so you can install it through iTunes.

There are no other options.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register for a developer certificate in [Apple.Developer](https://developer.apple.com/).Then create provisioning profiles and install it. Otherwise you cant install your app in a real device.

You can refer [this link](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/) for more info